# Azure Pipeline error Unable to locate executable file: 'databricks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I am trying to create CI/CD pipeline in azure databricks with azure devops using a windows self hosted agent. I am following this blog: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ci-cd-azure-databricks-using-devops-deepak-rajak I am getting this error and I am not able to resolve it any idea how can I resolve this?

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Pipeline error Unable to locate executable file: 'databricks

You could try to install the extension [DevOps for Azure Databricks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riserrad.azdo-databricks), and add the extension "Configure Databricks CLI" task before "Deploy Databricks Notebooks":

[image]